# Prevent sidebar from loading in mobile. (server side)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, server

How can I prevent my sidebar from loading resources on the server-side if the device is a mobile? I understand how to hide via CSS, but i'm more interested in preventing calls to the server.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a function called [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) that will check the user's `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` value and return `true` or `false`.

You can wrap your code in a conditional statement, for example:

```
if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {
    // Run code for desktop users
} else {
    // Run code for mobile users
}
```

Note, this can potentially be unreliable as clients can change their `HTTP_USER_AGENT` value. (Most normal users do not change this, however).

Answer (score 0):

Call `get_sidebar()` only if [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) is false.

That'll take a little bit of load off your server, but don't rely on perfect identification of mobile clients (e.g. still add "display: none"), and be aware that most caching solutions you might come across don't care about the user agent, which will lead to caching problems if you don't adjust for that.